# When I open my app from a play store link it doesn't load any activity and goes white screen

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, intentfilter

I have an application published in the play store. When I share the link on facebook or on other social and then I click on it from mobile, if the device has already the app instead of opening the play store it loads directly my application. The problem is that when it happens the app doesn't load any activity and got stuck on white screen. I think that this is probably related to the Application class but I don't know how to solve this.

```
public class AppGlobal extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // things that I must do by extending application

    if(DEBUG)
        Log.e("AppGlobal","Started");
   }
}
```

**Update:** This is the link that users click on the facebook posts. Please note that the behaviour I described occurs only when the post has been clicked on facebook app and the user has already installed my application on the same device.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={package-name-of-app}
```

When I try to clink the play store link this is the debug logging.

```
04-10 12:32:47.955 11111-11111/? E/Zygote: v2
04-10 12:32:47.956 11111-11111/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-10 12:32:49.056 11111-11111/it.mybeautifullApp E/AppGlobal: Started
```

I've also read online that this could be related to the lack of intent filters in the manifest, but I think that I've set them correctly:

**Update 2:** posted the whole manifest (updated with new deep linking attempts)

```
  <application
    android:name=".AppGlobal"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:allowBackup">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter android:label="from_play_store">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="play.google.com" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="from_play_store_market">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="market"
                android:host="details?id=it.cineprime" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".CheckoutActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SurveyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".BarcodeActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="it.cineprime.MainActivity.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".IntroActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarCollapsing" />
</application>
```

So the question is: How can I intercept when my application is called in the way described above or how can I at least avoid the white screen stuck?

Comment: You need to check which activity is launched when a `DeepLink` is clicked.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez How can i check this?

Comment: post your complete `menifest`

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez I have posted, it is maybe the custom tab activity of facebook the problem?

Comment: What does your `SplashActivity` contain? Is it white screen?

Comment: Yes, a white screen and also there's an Image view with a visual animation with a time handler. After the timer expires it should go to another activity but 1) No animation shown and 2) No Logtrace in splash activity and also 3) app stuck somewhere i can't figure out yet

Answer (score 0):

make `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>` in your theme for getting rid of white screen

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of URL you are using for linking to the app. Here is [some documentation on recommended formats](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html). Putting the URL you are sharing on social media in your question would help.

But you might want to read the [documentation on linking to specific content in your app](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html). I suspect you are using one of these links, but haven't set up the intent filter for it, [as described here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html).

Specifically you will need:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to handle default views in the Intent. I suspect the `<data>` coming in is not `@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme` so there is no activity to handle it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the new manifest and the URL you asked. Still not working. Is it possible that this is related to the BROWSABLE category?